# Is there a format for manual testing checklists?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, format, functional-testing

For our web app, Selenium testing doesn't make sense at the moment but we have a large number of undocumented manual testing scenarios that we'd like to capture to ship with our source code.

Is there a good existing, documented format (e.g. JSON-based) for building such a checklist?

Comment: 1. Chances are this is going to get closed as "too broad".
2. Chances are that the effort you will put into producing what you describe will be at least the same as producing some minimal automation. Start with Selenium IDE and see how far that will get you (and don't expect too with just the SeIDE).

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to collect tests from a large number of non-dev users so we'll probably try to accept both textual and Selenium tests simultaneously.

Comment: The advantage of the SeleniumIDE tests is that if/when you decide to do real automation, the SeIDE export feature gets you half-way to having coded tests in a language of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TestNG you can define your scenarios in testsuites (a group of related tests) in xml files. For example, we have a folder for each Scrum sprint, and in them we place one file for each User Story.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- US XX: As an user I want to access to the intranet with a login form in order to access to private resources -->
<suite name="IntranetLogin" enabled="true">
    <test name="LoginChecking" order-by-instances="true">       
        <classes>
            <class name="com.company.LoginTestSet" />
                <methods>
                    <include name="loginWithExistingUser" />
                    <include name="loginWithNonExistingUser" />
                    <include name="loginWithWrongPassword" />
                    <include name="loginWithBlockedUser" />
                    <include name="loginWithEmptyFields" />
                </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
    ...

</suite>
```

You can define the tests steps in the javadoc of each test method so they will appear in the html documentation that is auto generated when you compile. For example:

```
 /**
 * Description: Should display an error if the user try to log in with an incorrect password
 * 
 * Test steps:
 * 1) Go to the login page
 * 2) Write an username
 * 3) Write an incorrect password
 * 4) Click on Submit button
 *
 * Expected results:
 * - An error message is displayed
 * - The browser remains in the login page
 * */
```

And if you want a more expressive way to write the test steps you can take a look at Doxygen. [Here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/lists.html) hou have an example.

Answer (score 1):

for manual testing checking list we use Requirement Tractability Matrix (RTM) is a table (mostly a spreadsheet) which shows if each requirement has a respective Test case / cases to make sure if the requirement is covered for testing. It is basically used to ensure that ALL the requirements and Change Requests are or will be tested.